# How to get elapsed time from countdown timer to send to the server

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am making an Quiz app where i am showing an Countdowntimer. It is displaying countdowntimer in textfield and also showing progress in progressbar. But on quiz finish i want send time elapsed by the user to the server. How can i get elapsed time?

```
  countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10800000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            i[0]++;
            progressBar.setProgress((int) i[0] *100/(10800000/1000));

             timer.setText(String.format("%d : %d : %d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            i[0]++;
            progressBar.setProgress(100);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got idea from @quick learner .

```
long elapsed_time;

 countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10800000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            i[0]++;
            progressBar.setProgress((int) i[0] *100/(10800000/1000));

             timer.setText(String.format("%d : %d : %d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

             elapsed_time = 10800000-millisUntilFinished;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            i[0]++;
            progressBar.setProgress(100);

        }
    };
```

Comment: thats really good to know dear , the requirement was not clear at first , anyways you solved yourself :) Happy coding

Comment: did you manage the scenario where countdowntimer should stop if user answers before the given time?

Comment: Yes i written code for that in another function which is call when user press on finish button or back pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

**Declare this variable globally and use it**

```
private int elapsed_time = 10800000;

countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(elapsed_time, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            i[0]++;
            progressBar.setProgress((int) i[0] *100/(10800000/1000));

             timer.setText(String.format("%d : %d : %d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            i[0]++;
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            sendRequestToServerAPI(elapsed_time);
        }
    };
```

Comment: no its not working. It is sending same time as i declared.

Comment: i think thats what u wanted if the countdowntimer finishes

Comment: can you please explain what you actually want dear

Comment: suppose if i start countdown of 3 hours, and if user takes only 1 hour to complete then it should send only 1 hour to the server.